# Function of sum of sines from graph

Tags: functions, trigonometry

[image]

What would be the method to express the solid curve as a sum of sines in the form $$\Psi(x)=5(\sin(2 \pi a x) + \sin(2 \pi b x))$$

By calculating $\Psi(0.1)=5$, I used the properties of sine as an odd function and get $a=-b$, which does not work for the rest of the graph.

Comment: What is the solid curv?e Is it something like $10\cos x\sin 10x$?

Comment: You might want to look into what beats are in the context of waves/wave functions. They're quite used in physics

Answer (score 1):

Just use $\sin(2\pi ax)+\sin(2\pi bx)=2\sin(2\pi\frac{a+b}2)\cos(2\pi\frac{a-b}2)$. For $a\approx b$, the second term is the envelope of the oscillation (dashed line).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the two seperate oscillators:

$$\Phi_1 (x)=5sin(2\pi a x)=- 5cos(2\pi ax+\frac{\pi}{2})=-5 Re(e^{i(2\pi ax+\frac{\pi}{2})})$$
$$\Phi_2 (x)=sin(2\pi bx)=- cos(2\pi bx+\frac{\pi}{2})=-Re(e^{i(2\pi bx+\frac{\pi}{2})})$$

In physics, we usually add the complex versions of those seperate oscillators (by putting the common terms in evidence), because it's just a lot simpler then working with sines and cossines. Then your final function will be just the real part of the sum of those oscillators.